# How can I track location of particular mobile using android api

Tags: android

I can easily get location of my current device.
But here I want to find the location of another mobile for example: 99XXXXXXX, mob no 78XXXXXX
I can get current location of device by using the following code:

> locationManager =(LocationManager)
>   mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

How to get location of other mobiles?

Comment: Obviously you need the devices to willingly share this information with your cloud service, which you **securely** share with only other devices that agree to their location being shared with them. You don't seem to be willing to do this responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

Your app should ping its location to your server (something like location server) and from another mobile you can request particular location.

I don't think that would be too costly to save a unique ID and coordinates.